# buffering subprocess output to a file: io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno

Tags: python, io, subprocess

I would like to buffer an output of `grep` to a buffer and then read it with `pandas` to avoid loading a huge original file into memory:

```
import subprocess
import io
import pandas as pd

firstfile = "~/references/rs_hg19.snps.uniq.bed"
outf = io.StringIO("")
p0 = subprocess.Popen(('grep', '-P', "chr22\\t", firstfile), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p1 = subprocess.call(["head", "-n5", ], stdin=p0.stdout, stdout= outf)
p0.wait()
print(pd.read_table(outf)
    )
```

I am getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    p1 = subprocess.call(["head", "-n1", ], stdin=p0.stdout, stdout= outf)
  File "/opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib64/python3.3/subprocess.py", line 520, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "/opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib64/python3.3/subprocess.py", line 786, in __init__
    errread, errwrite) = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "/opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib64/python3.3/subprocess.py", line 1294, in _get_handles
    c2pwrite = stdout.fileno()
io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno
```

even though I run it directly, [not from any IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31080829/python-error-io-unsupportedoperation-fileno).

Any ideas / suggestions?

System 1: CentOS6.7, Python3.3

System 2: MacOSX10.10.5, Python3.5

Comment: Is there supposed to be a comma after `"-n1"`?

Comment: syntactically it does not matter

Answer (score 2):

You can do what you want by getting subprocess to read the stdout for you into a byte string. Replace your second call with

```
p1 = subprocess.Popen(["head", "-n5" ], stdin=p0.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
data = p1.communicate()[0]
string = data.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: that is a good beginning, but how do you feed it in `pandas`? It will not take bytes as input to `read_table`.

Comment: You can convert the bytes to a string if you know what encoding your original file uses. Eg add `string = data.decode('utf-8')`, then you have a python string.