# Python 3 Unsupported fileno

Tags: python, sockets, server, client

I am trying to run a client which communicates with its server.

As most examples of Python socket client do, I do:

```
while True:
        try:
            self.connect_list = [sys.stdin, self.clientSocket]
            self.readList, self.writeList, self.errorList = select.select(self.connect_list, [], [])
```

And the following error comes up:

```
File "C:/Users/.../ArduinoWiFiMaster.py", line 25, in comProtocol
self.readList, self.writeList, self.errorList = select.select(self.connect_list, [], [])
io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno
```

I have no idea why fileno is declared unsupported. Most of the examples online use similar code and say they work just as fine, but on my computer, they don't seem to work.

I use Python 3.5.2 GUI IDLE. Thank you for answering.

Comment: Looks like you are running from the command line, but I'll throw this out ther just in case... Are you running this from the interactive interpreter? In that case, you might [try running it directly from the command line](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31081957/1342445), ie: `python C:/Users/.../ArduinoWiFiMaster.py`

Comment: does self.clientSocket define fileno()?