# Python: Hello world with Flask gives me an error related to app.run(debug=True)

Tags: python, flask

I am new to Flask (and quite new to python) and I have tried running the following very basic script:

```
from flask import Flask
app= Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "This is the homepage"
if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I am using Python 3.6 and IDLE on Windows 10. 
The problem is I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Susy/Desktop/provaflask.py", line 7, in <module>
    app.run(debug=True)
  File "C:\Users\Susy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 936, in run
    cli.show_server_banner(self.env, self.debug, self.name, False)
  File "C:\Users\Susy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 630, in show_server_banner
    click.echo(message)
  File "C:\Users\Susy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\click\utils.py", line 217, in echo
    file = _default_text_stdout()
  File "C:\Users\Susy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\click\_compat.py", line 621, in func
    rv = wrapper_func()
  File "C:\Users\Susy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\click\_compat.py", line 385, in get_text_stdout
    rv = _get_windows_console_stream(sys.stdout, encoding, errors)
  File "C:\Users\Susy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\click\_winconsole.py", line 261, in _get_windows_console_stream
    func = _stream_factories.get(f.fileno())
io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno
```

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31080829/python-error-io-unsupportedoperation-fileno), the problem seems to be related to the use of IDLE, however I would like to keep using it, so can you please help? Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you can find out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31081957/2754195)
You have to run your script from straight up Python instead.

You have to save that file for example in `app.py`
and run from your command line:

```
python app.py
```

or in your exmaple:

`python C:/Users/Susy/Desktop/provaflask.py`