# Got error while executing the app.run(debug=True) line in Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

This is my code.

```
from flask import Flask
app=Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return "WebApp"

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And this is the error I encounter.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:/Python Projects/webapp1.py", line 7, in <module>
    app.run(debug=True)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 938, in run
    cli.show_server_banner(self.env, self.debug, self.name, False)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 629, in show_server_banner
    click.echo(message)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\click\utils.py", line 218, in echo
    file = _default_text_stdout()
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\click\_compat.py", line 675, in func
    rv = wrapper_func()
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\click\_compat.py", line 436, in get_text_stdout
    rv = _get_windows_console_stream(sys.stdout, encoding, errors)
File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\click\_winconsole.py", line 295, in _get_windows_console_stream
    func = _stream_factories.get(f.fileno())
io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno
```

I am new to Flask and currently have very little knowledge about it. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Hello world with Flask gives me an error related to app.run(debug=True)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50089690/python-hello-world-with-flask-gives-me-an-error-related-to-app-rundebug-true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug of the *click* package [issue 1021](https://github.com/pallets/click/issues/1021).

You can avoid it by running in the shell instead of in python idle.