# How to use python subprocess with bytes instead of files

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

I can convert a mp4 to wav, using `ffmpeg`, by doing this:

```
ffmpeg -vn test.wav  -i test.mp4
```

I can also use `subprocess` to do the same, as long as my input and output are filepaths.

But what if I wanted to use `ffmpeg` directly on bytes or a "file-like" object like `io.BytesIO()`?

Here's an attempt at it:

```py
import subprocess
from io import BytesIO
b = BytesIO()

with open('test.mp4', 'rb') as stream:
    command = ['ffmpeg', '-i']
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=b)
    proc.communicate(input=stream.read())
    proc.wait()
    proc.stdin.close()
    proc.stdout.close()
```

Gives me:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnsupportedOperation                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-0ddce839ebc9> in <module>
      5 with open('test.mp4', 'rb') as stream:
      6     command = ['ffmpeg', '-i']
----> 7     proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=b)
...
   1486                 # Assuming file-like object
-> 1487                 c2pwrite = stdout.fileno()
   1488 
   1489             if stderr is None:

UnsupportedOperation: fileno
```

Of course, I could use temp files to funnel my bytes, but I'd like to be able to avoid writing to the disk (because this step is just one link in a pipeline of transformations).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31080829/python-error-io-unsupportedoperation-fileno could be worth a look

Comment: Apparently `BytesIO` object don't have a `fileno()` method — not too surprising, really.

Comment: @DaveIdito: I tried in a separate script, but get the same error.

Comment: @martineau: Yes, that's what the traceback says. The question is, how to make it work: "it" being, the mp4-to-wav extraction, but without using a "physical file" -- instead going from bytes of mp4 to bytes of wav. In fact, the question is not specific to ffmpeg, but to any situation where we want to call a system command that uses files, but we want to use bytes.

Comment: You might have some luck emulating files using pipes or similar objects, but this depends on what the application actually expects to do with its input. This can't be solved in a general way - a program expecting files may very well expect *actual* files, including file path, stat, xattrs and so on.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: You've nailed my meta-question (but it seems concrete questions have more chances of being answered here). You say "actual files, including file path, stat, xattrs and so on". My meta is: "How does one get a in-RAM equivalent to an actual file in python?". BytesIO doesn't go the whole way. So how can one go further?

Comment: What you're describing is aka a "ram-disk". Python doesn't have one, much less one that external processes could also use.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Base on @thorwhalen's answer, here's how it would work from bytes to bytes. 
What you were probably missing @thorwhalen, is the actual pipe-to-pipe way to send and get data when interacting with a process. When sending bytes, the stdin should be closed before the process can read from it.

```py
def from_bytes_to_bytes(
        input_bytes: bytes,
        action: str = "-f wav -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -ar 44100")-> bytes or None:
    command = f"ffmpeg -y -i /dev/stdin -f nut {action} -"
    ffmpeg_cmd = subprocess.Popen(
        shlex.split(command),
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        shell=False
    )
    b = b''
    # write bytes to processe's stdin and close the pipe to pass
    # data to piped process
    ffmpeg_cmd.stdin.write(input_bytes)
    ffmpeg_cmd.stdin.close()
    while True:
        output = ffmpeg_cmd.stdout.read()
        if len(output) > 0:
            b += output
        else:
            error_msg = ffmpeg_cmd.poll()
            if error_msg is not None:
                break
    return b
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a partial answer: three functions showing how this can be done from file to file (for completeness), from bytes to file, and from file to bytes. The bytes to bytes solution is fighting back though.

```py
import shlex
import subprocess

def from_file_to_file(input_file: str, output_file: str, action="-f wav -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -ar 44100"):
    command = f"ffmpeg -i {input_file} {action} -vn {output_file}"
    subprocess.call(shlex.split(command))


def from_file_to_bytes(input_file: str, action="-f wav -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1 -ar 44100"):
    command = f"ffmpeg -i {input_file} {action} -"

    ffmpeg_cmd = subprocess.Popen(
        shlex.split(command),
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        shell=False
    )
    b = b''
    while True:
        output = ffmpeg_cmd.stdout.read()
        if len(output) > 0:
            b += output
        else:
            error_msg = ffmpeg_cmd.poll()
            if error_msg is not None:
                break
    return b


def from_bytes_to_file(input_bytes, output_file, action="-f wav -acodec pcm_s16le -ac 1"):
    command = f"ffmpeg -i /dev/stdin {action} -vn {output_file}"
    ffmpeg_cmd = subprocess.Popen(
        shlex.split(command),
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        shell=False
    )
    ffmpeg_cmd.communicate(input_bytes)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution I came up with recently although I had used AWS and GCP bucket objects as the input and output.
I'm not an expert on python by any means but this got me the results I was after.

You need to install ffmpeg on your local machine and add it to the environment variables to have access to ffmpeg.

If you're using the cloud, ffmpeg comes pre-installed on google cloud functions and there is a Lambda Layer on the repository library for AWS that you can leverage.

Hopefully someone gets use out of this. :)

```
import subprocess

# tested against 'wav', 'mp3', 'flac', 'mp4'
desired_output = 'mp3'
track_input = 'C:\\Users\\.....\\track.wav'
track_output = f'C:\\Users\\......\\output_track.{desired_output}'

encoded_type = ''
format_for_conversion = desired_output 

if desired_output =='m4a':
    encoded_type= '-c:a aac'
    format_for_conversion = 'adts'

with open(track_input, "rb") as in_track_file:
    data = in_track_file.read()

input_track_data= bytearray(data)

# using pipe:0 refers to the stdin, pipe:1 refers to stdout
ffmpeg_command = f'ffmpeg  -i pipe:0 {encoded_type} -f {format_for_conversion} pipe:1 '

ffmpeg_process = subprocess.Popen(ffmpeg_command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

output_stream = ffmpeg_process.communicate(input_track_data)
# comes back as a tuple
output_bytes = output_stream[0]

with open(track_output, 'ab') as f:
    delete_content(f)
    f.write(output_bytes)
```

Comment: Thanks @sobblesbobbles for this solution. Does your solution work with video? I want to download a ts file, convert to h265 mp4, then push to AWS, without writing to disk. When I try this with your method only the audio track seems to come through. My command is `ffmpeg -i pipe:0 -c:v libx265 -c:a copy -f avi pipe:1`. Side note that your delete_content() function hasn't been defined in your example (it doesn't seem to be needed anyways)

Comment: Thank you for the solution!
I run it with my macos python, and the only I had to add `.split()` to the `ffmpeg_command` to make it working.