# Broken pipe when closing subprocess pipe with FFmpeg

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, mp4

First, I'm a total noob with ffmpeg. That said, similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61602547/how-to-use-python-subprocess-with-bytes-instead-of-files) question, I'm trying to read a video file as bytes and extract 1 frame as a thumbnail image, as bytes, so I can upload the thumbnail to AWS S3. I don't want to save files to disk and then have to delete them. I modified the accepted answer in the aforementioned question for my purposes, which is to handle different file formats, not just video. Image files work just fine with this code, but an mp4 breaks the pipe at `byte_command.stdin.close()`. I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but can't figure it out.

The input bytes are a valid mp4, as I'm getting the following in the Terminal:

```
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isom
  Duration: 00:02:48.48, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x480, 486 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mjpeg (native))
```

from FFmpeg when I write to stdin.

---

My FFmpeg command I'm passing in:
`ffmpeg -i /dev/stdin -f image2pipe -frames:v 1 -`

I've tried numerous variations of this command, with `-f nut`, `-f ...` etc, to no avail.

---

At the command line, without using python or subprocess, I've tried:
`ffmpeg -i /var/www/app/thumbnail/movie.mp4 -frames:v 1 output.png` and I get a nice png image of the video.

---

My method:

```py
def get_converted_bytes_from_bytes(input_bytes: bytes, command: str) -> bytes or None:
    byte_command = subprocess.Popen(
        shlex.split(command),
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        shell=False,
        bufsize=10 ** 8,
    )
    b = b""

    byte_command.stdin.write(input_bytes)
    byte_command.stdin.close()
    while True:
        output = byte_command.stdout.read()
        if len(output) > 0:
            b += output
        else:
            error_msg = byte_command.poll()
            if error_msg is not None:
                break
    return b
```

What am I missing? Thank you!

---

UPDATE, AS REQUESTED:

Code Sample:

```
import shlex
import subprocess


def get_converted_bytes_from_bytes(input_bytes: bytes, command: str) -> bytes or None:
    byte_command = subprocess.Popen(
        shlex.split(command),
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        shell=False,
        bufsize=10 ** 8,
    )
    b = b""
    # write bytes to processe's stdin and close the pipe to pass
    # data to piped process
    byte_command.stdin.write(input_bytes)
    byte_command.stdin.close()
    while True:
        output = byte_command.stdout.read()
        if len(output) > 0:
            b += output
        else:
            error_msg = byte_command.poll()
            if error_msg is not None:
                break
    return b


def run():
    subprocess.run(
        shlex.split(
            "ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=640x480:rate=1 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 23 -t 5 test.mp4"
        )
    )
    with open("test.mp4", "rb") as mp4:
        b1 = mp4.read()
        b = get_converted_bytes_from_bytes(
            b1,
            "ffmpeg -y -loglevel error -i /dev/stdin -f image2pipe -frames:v 1 -",
        )
        print(b)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Comment: Can you please post a reproducible code sample that one can copy paste and execute? You can use the following command for building synthetic video file (to be used as input for your code sample): `subprocess.run('ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=640x480:rate=1 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 23 -t 5 test.mp4')`

Comment: @Rotem, I receive `No such file or directory` when I try to run that command

Comment: Sorry, I am not used to Linux. Try: `subprocess.run(shlex.split('ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=640x480:rate=1 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 23 -t 5 test.mp4'))` or use full path: `subprocess.run(shlex.split('/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=640x480:rate=1 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 23 -t 5 test.mp4'))`

Comment: Thanks. That works better :-)

Comment: Well that's frustrating. Building a reproducible code sample, and my code works fine. I've updated my question with the code sample, but unfortunately it doesn't cause the underlying issue I'm having.

Comment: I've tried two separate mp4 files. The first is 11 mb, the second is 6. Both of them cause the problem, whereas the mp4 created by the command you provided does not. Would it be a problem with the size of the video? Grasping at straws here

Comment: It is probably related to the size of the video. Try to create a larger video (500 seconds long instead of 5 seconds).

Comment: 500 second video broke the pipe as well. I guess the question I really need to ask then is how to chunk the bytes and process just the first few seconds.

Comment: In most cases it is not going to work with **MP4** container. MP4 file has a [moov atom](https://sanjeev-pandey.medium.com/understanding-the-mpeg-4-moov-atom-pseudo-streaming-in-mp4-93935e1b9e9a). In most cases the moov atom location is at the end of the file. When passing MP4 to FFmpeg, the FFmpeg looks for the moov atom, before start parsing the data. You can create MP4 with moov atom at the beginning of the file: `subprocess.run('ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=640x480:rate=1 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 23 -t 500 -movflags +faststart test.mp4')`. Is it relevant?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230810/discussion-between-shawn-and-rotem).