# io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno even in PowerShell with Administration permissions

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multithreading, pyserial

So I'm trying to read data from a serial port using `asyncio`. I have a function called `start_receiver` as below.

```
def start_receiver(ser, exit_queue, msg_queue):
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.add_reader(ser.fileno(), receiver, ser, msg_queue)
    loop.run_until_complete(forever(exit_queue))
    loop.close()
```

and the `receiver` function

```
def receiver(file_descriptor, queue):
    # Reading 1 byte, followed by whatever is left in the
    # read buffer, as suggested by the developer of PySerial.
    buff = file_descriptor.read()
    buff = buff + file_descriptor.read(file_descriptor.inWaiting())
    while buff:
        while buff[0] != b'\x02':
            buff = buff[1:]
        x = buff[1:]
        buff = []
        queue.put_nowait(pickle.dumps((x, datetime.now()), protocol=5))
```

`ser` is called as `ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 38400, timeout=0)`

For some reason, I got the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 946, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "\PycharmProjects\serialReading\receiver.py", line 13, in start_receiver
    loop.add_reader(ser.fileno(), receiver, ser, msg_queue)
io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno
```

I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31080829/python-error-io-unsupportedoperation-fileno) and I've tried to activate my virtual env and launch the script from the Windows Power Shell (I'm using Win10) as Administrator but I got the same error.

Is there a way to work around or fix the issue?

Comment: does it raise by PySerial? or `asyncio`? `fileno()` may be not supported on Windows. or the event loop on Windows does not support that kind of `fileno` (to my knowledge, only socket fileno is supported). Try it on Linux or use sync code instead?

Comment: @Aaron yeah, i figured it out it could be a Windows issue that does no support that kind of operation. I'll try Linux